# Select rows with non-NA values in at least one of the desired columns

Tags: r, dataframe, na, missing-data

I have this code that works fine:

```
CompleteCoxObs<-temp[is.na(temp[,8])== FALSE | is.na(temp[,9])== FALSE | is.na(temp[,10])== FALSE,];
```

What is a better and more efficient way to achieve the same result?

Comment: See the `na.omit` function

Comment: also shorthand for `is.na(x) == FALSE` is `!is.na(x)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this to check for all the columns:

```
CompleteCox.df <- temp.df[rowSums(is.na(temp.df)) != ncol(temp.df),]
```

In your case:

```
CompleteCox.df <- temp.df[rowSums(is.na(temp.df[, c(8,9,10)])) != 3,]
```

Comment: This is a very elegant solution, thanks! However, this translates to "where at least one column of temp.df isn't NA", correct? My data frame has 16 columns and I only want to apply this to 3 of them (cols 8,9,10) so I will need to slightly modify your code.

Comment: @nasim Now try it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try one of the followings:

```
temp[!is.na(rowSums(temp[,8:10])),]
```

or

```
temp[!apply(is.na(temp[,8:10]),1,any),]
```

or

```
temp[na.omit(temp[,8:10]),]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
temp[apply(!is.na(temp[,8:10]),1,any),]
```

Note placing the "!" in front of `is.na`